# Get the inner content of a parent div with JSOUP

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to get the content of a page (URL), of a specific div tag. I manage to get that whole tag but i can not remove it.

```
Document page_source = Jsoup.connect(current_url).get();
Elements info = page_source.select("div.article#single");
```

The content that am getting is like:

```
<div class="article" id="single">    
  <p>qwerty</p>
  <p>qwerty</p> 
</div>
```

I want only:

```
  <p>qwerty</p>
  <p>qwerty</p>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: This is expected. Read the javazon to find your answer.

Comment: OK, so what should i change in order to take the desire output? I tried unwrap() but it return NULL if its the parent tag

Comment: You need all children of the selected element. There's a method for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the whole tags when you access the elements object directly. You could rely on html() for getting inner content alone. For example

```
Elements info = doc.select("div.article#single");

// The whole element or toString of elements
// Prints : <div class="article" id="single"> 
//      <p>qwerty</p> 
//      <p>qwerty</p> 
//      </div>
System.out.println(info);


// The html content
// Prints : <p>qwerty</p> 
//      <p>qwerty</p>
System.out.println(info.html());


// The actual value of nodes
// Prints : qwerty qwerty
System.out.println(info.text());
```